# ATmega16A SMD Package Stop Working after afew hours

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude, atmega16

نتایج ترجمه
Hello
I wrote a program for ATmega16A microcontroller, 6 of the pins are defined as input and 6 of the pins are defined as output.
UART communication and a timer are also defined in the program.

There is no problem when I program the software on the DIP package.
But on the SMD package, the micro stops working after a few hours and does not work even after resetting.

I wrote the program in C
and I programmed with avrdude.
Hex file size: 8.5 KB

Is it possible that the problem is with my codes?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. You have provided very little information

Comment: It is possible. Occasional halts often related to issues in interrupt handlers. It is also possible you have some issues with the schematics (e.g not all VCC AVCC are powered, or power not decoupled with capacitors etc.). You need to provide more information

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the problem was fixed by reducing the size of the software.But still my question is wy works well on DIP but not on SMD